# how to update array of object in mongodb with for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i want to update nested mongo document with for loop here is my node.js code;

```
//loop starts
    var update = {
      "rate":mainRate,
      "classifierCategories."+e+".rate":temiz[i].slice(0,2)
    };

    classifier.update({"classifierShortName":arrFile[1]},update,function(err){
    console.log("updated - "+i+" - "+e);
    });
//loop end
```

Error accurs ;

```
Unexpected token +
```

How can i update classifierCategories array with for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is how you are trying to notate the object "keys". This isn't valid for key construction in JavaScript object as the key names are literal and all characters are considered part of the name string.

Notate like this instead:

```js
var update = { "rate": minRate };
update["classifierCategories."+e+".rate"] = temiz[i].slice(0,2);
```

That allows you to dynamically assign the key name like you want.